# Top n keys in a list of dicts?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have data which looks like this:

```
data = [
{'item': "A", 'price': 100}, 
{'item': "B", 'price': 200}, 
{'item': "C", 'price': 300}, 
{'item': "D", 'price': 800}
]
```

Is there a way to return the name of the top `n` most expensive items?

Comment: Just sort it and take the first `n` items: `sorted(data, key=lambda x: x['price'], reverse=True)`

Comment: Is there any particular reason for using that structure for your data? Seems like that could all be in one `dict`, that looks like this: `{"A":100,"B":200,"C":300,"D":800}`. Or it could even be a list of objects with instance variables for `name` and `price`.

Comment: @MarkMeyer Your comment could definitely be an answer if you fleshed it out with some details and/or code comments.

Comment: It's almost certainly a dupe @mypetlion — just don't have time to search right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort the list with using `operator.itemgetter` as the `key` so that the objects are sorted by price and then select the top `n`

```py
from operator import itemgetter
sorted(data, key=itemgetter('price'), reverse=True)[:n]
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally frowned upon on this site. Please edit your answer to include an explanation of what your code does and how it solves OP's problem.

Comment: Would be better to use `heapq.nlargest` instead of sorting and slicing.

Answer (score 1):

As a more algorithmic approach, you can use a min heap of size n to keep track of the top n elements. You can use python's heapq library which is very easy:

```
import heapq

# pushing to the heap
heap = []
heapq.heappush(heap, (100, "A"))

# popping from the heap
price, item = heapq.heappop()
```

The `(100, "A")` tuple is needed to give the priority in the max heap and to maintain a mapping between prices and items. `100` is the priority - the key used when sorting in the heap. "A" is simply the item associated and isn't used in any calculation, it just makes it finding the element associated with the price easy.

A basic algorithm for this approach would look like the following:

```
import heapq
def find_top_k_elements(data, k):
    heap = []
    for row in data:
        if len(heap) < k:
            heapq.heappush(heap, (row["price"], row["item"]))
        else:
            # if the current price we are looking at is larger
            # than the smallest price in the heap
            if row["price"] > heap[0][0]:
                # add it to the heap
                heapq.heappush(heap, (row["price"], row["item"]))
                # we now have k + 1 elements in the heap
                # we need to pop the smallest element
                heapq.heappop()
    result = []
    while heap:
        # add the item name to result list
        result.append(heapq.heappop()[1])
```

The need for the extra `result` array is 1) if you need the items in order of ascending price and 2) the heap has the tuple coupling (price, item) where as you only want the item. In theory you could just return the heap if you don't care about formatting and just want the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy implementation that will print only the top n values of your data:

```
data = [
    {'item': "A", 'price': 100},
    {'item': "B", 'price': 200},
    {'item': "C", 'price': 300},
    {'item': "D", 'price': 800}
]

n = 2
print(sorted(data, key=lambda x: x['price'], reverse=True)[:n])
```